# ostringstream overloading const char * with the void *

Tags: c++

im having an issue with the ostream, I have written a very basic macro that should print out its parameters.

Please see example code below:

```
#define LOG Message(__FILE__, __LINE__,__func__)

class Message : public std::ostringstream 
{
    public:
        Message(const char *param1, int param2, const char *param3)
        {
            *this<<param3<<"("<<param1<<":"<<param2<<")";
        }
        ~Message()
        {
            *this<<endl;
            cout<< rdbuf()->str();
        }
};


int main()
{
    int integer = 1;
    string str = "XYZ";

    LOG<<integer<<"DEBUGLOG1: "<<str<<" "<<integer;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is if I use:

```
LOG << "LOG1: " << str << " " << integer;
```

The output prints the Address* of the const char* "LOG1: " rather than the value.

But,
If I use:

```
LOG << integer << "DEBUGLOG1: " << str << " " << integer;
```

The output works perfect, printing the integer value and the char value.

it looks like instead of using `ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const char* s );`

it is using `ostream& operator<< (const void* val);` ?

Can anyone shed any light on what can be done to overcome this overloading please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use `#define LOG (std::cout << __FILE__ << __LINE__ << __func__)`?

Comment: Thanks, due to the performance impact this would flag I could not

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `Message(...)` is a temporary. The temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference parameter for `operator<<`.

It can only be used with member functions and operators, like `ostream::operator<<(int)`.

The odd thing is that the member operator returns a reference which can, in turn, be used with the non-member operators.

Comment: One possible solution is to take advantage of what you called  "*the odd thing*". If we replace the macro with: `#define LOG Message(__FILE__, __LINE__,__func__).flush()` it's all better.

Comment: But we know that the stream is empty at that point, so there is (semantically, at least) no disadvantage.

Comment: @Robᵩ: No the stream is _not_ empty at that point because the constructor (which has just completed) has already written some things to the stream.

Comment: @Rob - Right, and (thinking about it) for a stringstream `flush` doesn't do anything anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Precompile and see what the macro is getting unraveled as.  Working with macros is difficult (and unadvisable...)  and this is a very essentially debugging method you'll need to know to avoid keep reaching for Google or SO.

I believe you want `g++ -E`.

Comment: As Bo has pointed out, this is a very subtle problem that I'm sure a number of people might miss ... simply expanding the macro (at least for a simple one like this) won't exactly help that issue.

Comment: After preprocessing it would be possible to research the right question instead of being unable to isolate the problem to the C++ class magic instead of the C macro magic.  Perhaps this wouldn't have given the entire answer but it's the first step.

Comment: This is a very simple macro ... I think it's plainly evident what it's expanding to.